# yacc shift/reduce conflict when parse C ++ template arguments

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, yacc

I have a YACC grammar for parsing expressions in C++. Here is lite version:

```
// yacc.y
%token IDENT

%%

expr:
    call_expr
    | expr '<' call_expr
    | expr '>' call_expr
    ;

call_expr:
    IDENT
    | '(' expr ')'
    | IDENT '<' args '>' '(' args ')'
    ;

args:
    IDENT
    | args ',' IDENT
    ;

%%
```

When I want to support function call with template arguments, I got a `shift/reduce` conflict.

When we got input `IDENT '<' IDENT`, yacc doesn't know whether we should shift or reduce.

I want `IDENT '<' args '>' '(' args ')'` got higher precedence level than `expr '<' call_expr`, so I can parse the following exprs.

```
x < y
f<x>(a,b)
f<x,y>(a,b) < g<x,y>(c,d)
```

I see C++/C# both support this syntax. Is there any way to solve this problem with yacc?

How do I modify the `.y` file?

Thank you!

Comment: The C++ grammar is not LALR(1), so to the best of my knowledge there is no way to parse C++ code with `yacc`.  If you use `bison` and switch to GLR mode, you should be able to parse it.

Comment: Oh, great! I'm using `bison`. Could you tell me how to parse this by using GLR mode?Thank you very much!!!

Comment: This page has some details: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Simple-GLR-Parsers.html .  That said, you might want to read up on how GLR works, since you will need to do some extra processing.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Even with GLR you cannot resolve the conflict in `f<x>(a)` without knowing whether `f` is a template or not. All GLR can do is provide you with both possible parses (which will turn into an exponential number of parses for the full program).

Comment: @rici- Perhaps I'm mistaken about this, but can't you instruct the GLR parser to ignore one branch based on the semantic information you have?  My understanding is that you could maintain semantic information about what types / templates were in scope, inspect both parses to determine that the proper parse is as a template, then reject the other branch.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: I wonder how to parse this...Previously, I try to use ANTLR to parse this but failed, so I turn to use yacc...

Comment: What if I can't know the type of `f`? Can I just set the precedence?

Comment: @templatetypedef: if you had the semantic information available, you could parse it without GLR. You just restrict the template expansion production to `TEMPLATE_ID '<' expr_list '>'`. (That means you need to information available in your lexer, so the lexer and the parser need to share a symbol table. No big deal.) (And, yes, I'm leaving out lots of details.) (And you could do it the way you suggest with GLR, but I suspect it would be even more complicated.)

Comment: @curimit: No. You really cannot tell which is the correct parse unless you know what `f` is (at least, in my example).

Comment: @rici That's true if we want to emulate the C++ behaviour exactly. However the way I read the question, I think curimit just wants `x<y>(z)` to be parsed as a call to a template function and never as "(x less than y) greater than z" - whether `x` actually is a template or not.

Comment: @sepp2k: possibly true. That one could be achieved with GLR, but not easily with LALR(1). However, it will occasionally produce some unexpected results: `if_both(x<1, y>(x+1)*(x+1), 42)`. Personally, I'd go with `D`, which doesn't make `<` ambiguous.

Comment: @sepp2k I don't know how you can possibly draw that conclusion when the posted grammar is an expression grammar containing both '<' and '>' as operators, and when the OP says he has a grammar for parsing expressions, or when the parser resulting from your suggestion parser would be of use to neither man nor beast.

Comment: @EJP All this would mean would be that you can't use `<` followed by `>` as operators in the same expression unless you parenthesized the use of `<`, i.e. unless you wrote `(x < y) > z` instead of `x < y > z`. I don't see how that makes it useless to man and beast.

Comment: @sepp2k You've just described what makes it useless to man or beast. The OP hasn't said anything about parsing a restriced form of expressions. He said he wants to parse expressions, period. It's best to answer the question that is actually asked.

Comment: @EJP The OP also said that he wants `IDENT '<' args '>' '(' args ')'` to have "higher precedence" than `expr '<' call_expr`.

Comment: My suspicion is OP simply didn't understand what a mess template expression parsing in C++ is.  So the message for him is that to make progress he has to choose whether he wants to produce the *right* parse (he'll need type information), he's ok with an ambiguous parse, or when there's an ambiguity, he's willing to choose a default answer [meaning he's ok with it being the wrong parse sometimes].  Otherwise you have to offer 3 solutions, one for each choice.

Comment: Yes, I'm ok with an ambiguous parse.I'm trying to use `%glr-parser`.Thank all of you for all of answers.

Comment: @sepp2k: did you see my second example? It's not just in the "same expression" (maybe, depending on how you define that). It might be very difficult to explain the need for the apparently redundant parentheses around the first argument in this function call: `foo((x<z), y>(x+1)*(x+1))`. (Yes, you could put the redundant parentheses around the second argument. Of course, there might be intermediate arguments as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `-v` option to yacc/bison.  It will give you a .output file with all the info about the generated shift/reduce parser.  With your grammar, bison gives you:

```
State 1 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
      :
state 1

    4 call_expr: IDENT .
    6          | IDENT . '<' args '>' '(' args ')'

    '<'  shift, and go to state 5

    '<'       [reduce using rule 4 (call_expr)]
    $default  reduce using rule 4 (call_expr)
```

which shows you where the problem is.  After seeing an `IDENT`, when the next token is `<`, it doesn't know if it should reduce that `call_expr` (to ultimately match the rule `expr: expr '<' call_expr`) or if it should shift to match rule 6.

Parsing this with only 1 token lookahead is hard, as you have two distinct meanings of the token `<` (less-than or open angle bracket), and which is meant depends on the later tokens.

This case is actually even worse, as it is ambiguous, as an input like

```
a < b > ( c )
```

is probably a template call with both args lists being singletons, but it could also be

```
( a < b ) > ( c )
```

so just unfactoring the grammar won't help.  Your best bet is to use a more powerful parsing method, like bison's `%glr-parser` option or [btyacc](http://www.siber.com/btyacc/)

Comment: glr-parser or btyacc solve this by trying `IDENT '<' args '>' '(' args ')'` first, if failed then try `expr '<' call_expr`?

Comment: btyacc does one, then the other if the first fails -- you use YYVALID and YYERROR macros in actions to say when a parse fails or succeeds.  glr-parser does both, and requires %merge or %dprec to figure out which to use.